# Subir una imagen a hostinger con web services

Tags: php, android, android-studio, webservice, hosting

Tengo una cuenta con hostinger y deseo subir una imagen por medio de un web services con php veo que la imagen pasa a la base de datos pero no se graba en la carpeta raiz del hosting. Adjunto mi codigo de php que es muy simple

```
   <?php

$cnx=new  PDO("mysql:host=mysql.hvbnvr.com;dbname=u1fhghfh","u17gfhfggft","I0@hfghfghfghfghFy");

$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
    $imagen=$_POST["imagen"];

    $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());
    $path="dacepsacgde.com/solicitudfalta/$nombre.jpg";

        file_put_contents("$path", base64_decode($imagen));

        $bytesArchivo=file_get_contents($path);

    $res=$cnx->query("insert into solicitudfaltas values(null,'file_get_contents($imagen)')");


        if($res > 0){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "failed";
        }

?>
```

El problema es que si graba en la base de datos pero no en el servidor. Ya entrege todos los permisos que me brinda hostinger si alguien me puede ayudar con este tema lo agradeceria bastante.

Comment: Veo muchas inconsistencias en tu código... A veces se hace uso de `file_get_contents($path)` y otras de `file_get_contents($imagen)`, entiendo que `$imagen` guarda el contenido de la imagen, no su ruta. Por otro lado, no tiene ningún sentido que hagas esto `"$path"`, ya que `$path` ya es una cadena. ¿Es `$path` una ruta accesible desde la ubicación del script ejecutado? Compruébalo guardando un fichero cualquiera en esa ubicación e intentando un `file_get_contents` cobre él.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener un archivo se utilizar `$_FILE` no `$_POST`. Tambien deberias de eliminar las comillas en file_put_contents("$path",...) ya que $path es una variable.

Aqui el codigo completo:

```
<?php

    $cnx=new  PDO("mysql:host=mysql.hvbnvr.com;dbname=u1fhghfh","u17gfhfggft","I0@hfghfghfghfghFy");

    $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
    $imagen=$_FILE["imagen"];

    $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());
    $path= "dacepsacgde.com/solicitudfalta/$nombre.jpg";

    file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($imagen));

    $bytesArchivo = file_get_contents($path);
    $res=$cnx->query("insert into solicitudfaltas values(null,'file_get_contents($imagen)')");


    if($res > 0){
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "failed";
    }

?>
```